# Tint menu icons based on if condition

Tags: android, xml, kotlin

I have a toolbar:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/add_row"
        android:icon="@drawable/add"
        android:title="Add Row"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/clear_row"
        android:icon="@drawable/clear"
        android:title="Clear"
        />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/submit_row"
        android:icon="@drawable/check"
        android:title="Save"
        />
</menu>
```

The add (1) and save (3) buttons should be a green colour when enabled. The clear (2) should be red when enabled. All should be grey when disabled.
I can't seem to find a way to colour these as stated. I am using the tint when adding the toolbar into the screen:

```
app:itemIconTint="@drawable/toolbar_selector"
app:itemTextColor="@drawable/toolbar_selector"
```

However this only sets checked and standard colour. 
There doesn't seem to be a way to specify that the clear (2) item should have a red colour. Is this even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean when you click the icon once it turns green(enabled) when it is clicked again it turns gray(disabled) and so on? Then try this.

```
boolean isAddEnabled = false;
boolean isClearEnabled = false;
boolean isSubmitEnabled = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu);
    toolbar.setOnMenuItemClickListener(new Toolbar.OnMenuItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onMenuItemClick(MenuItem item) {

            int itemId = item.getItemId();

            switch (itemId) {
                case R.id.add_row:

                    if (!isAddEnabled) {

                        isAddEnabled = true;

                        item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                        break;
                    }
                    else {

                        isAddEnabled = false;

                        item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);

                        break;
                    }

                case R.id.clear_row:

                    if (!isClearEnabled) {

                        isClearEnabled = true;
                        item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.RED, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        break;
                    }
                    else {

                        isClearEnabled = false;
                        item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        break;
                    }

                case R.id.submit_row:

                    if (!isSubmitEnabled) {
                        isSubmitEnabled = true;
                        item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GREEN, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        break;
                    }
                    else {

                        isSubmitEnabled = false;
                        item.getIcon().setColorFilter(Color.GRAY, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
                        break;
                    }
            }
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Almost - I do want to change based on them being enabled and have cases for those situations but I want these different colours on load of the screen.
Therefore changing the colour on button press would not work.
I'll try doing something similar on load of the screen and loop through the items.